# Asymptotics of the Lattice Green Function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

Let
$$
\mu_k=\sum_{i=1}^d (2\sin (k_i/2))^2, \quad k\in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
Then it's not hard to show that if $d>2$, then
$$
\int_{(-\pi,\pi]^d} \frac{e^{ikx}}{\mu_k} dk =\frac{1}{|x|^{d-2}}C_d(x), \quad x\in \mathbb{Z}^d
$$
where $C_d(x)\to\text{const}$ as $x\to \infty$, or formally,
$$
C_d(x)\to \int \frac{e^{ip_1}}{p^2} dp,  \quad |x|\to\infty
$$
It then seems reasonable to say that $C_d(x) = \text{const} +O(|x|^{-\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon >0$. However, how would one go about to prove this?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.04717

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam The paper points out that the error of the lattice Green function (with respect to $1/|x|^{d-2}$) is $\sim 1/|x|^d$. It claims that it can be proven using the local central limit theorem (LCLT), but those references don't tackle this specific problem. They seem to prove something more general, which unfortunately, is making it difficult for me to follow. Do you know of a more direct proof (using the LCLT)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Also, you should edit your question. Right now, it is not clear at all that what you are asking about is a bound on the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a nice solution using the local central limit theorem. Let me provide a sketch of the proof, since it's a lot to write down.

> **Theorem**. Let $d>2$. Then the lattice Green function $C(x)$ satisfies
> $$
> C(x) \equiv\int_{(-\pi,\pi]^d} \frac{dk}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{ikx}}{\mu_k} =\frac{c_d}{|x|^{d-2}}+O\left( \frac{1}{|x|^d} \right)
> $$
> where $c_d$ is a constant such that $c_d/|x|^{d-2}$ is the Fourier transform (as tempered distribution) of $1/k^2$, i.e., the continuum Green function $G(x)$, formally written as,
> $$
> G(x) \equiv\int\frac{dk}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2} =\frac{c_d}{|x|^{d-2}} 
> $$

To prove this, we will need the local central limit theorem, i.e.,

> **Lemma (LCLT)**. Consider a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with transition matrix $p$ and let $p_n(x) =p^n(0,x)$ be the probability of starting at $0$ and ending at $x$ after $n$ steps. Define $\bar{p}_0(x)=\delta(x)$ and
> $$
> \bar{p}_n(x) = 2 \left( \frac{d}{2\pi n} \right)^{d/2} e^{-dx^2/2n}
> $$
> Then the error $E_n(x) = p_n(x) -\bar{p}_n(x)$ satisfies
> $$
> E_n(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{2m}} O\left( \frac{1}{n^{(d+2-2m)/2}}\right), \quad m\in \mathbb{N}
> $$

Also notice that the lattice Green function is equal to
$$
C(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(x)
$$
which you can show using the fact that the characteristic function $\varphi_n(k)$ of $p_n(x)$ is equal to $=\varphi(x)^n$ where $\varphi(x)$ is the characteristic function of $p(x)$.  From my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068210/inverse-fourier-transform-of-1-k2-in-mathbbrn/3983232#3983232), you see that the continuum lattice Green function can be written as
$$
G(x)= \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\int_\epsilon^\infty t^{-d/2} e^{-x^2/4t} dt
$$
Notice the similarity between $G(x)$ and $\sum \bar{p}_n(x)$. Using the lemma, we can do some approximations that will ultimately lead to an error $O(|x|^{-d})$. I might try to fill in the details later on.