# Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Does talking about the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}}$ even make sense? If it does, how can we conclude about the decay properties, support and smoothness of the inverse Fourier transform? I am learning about the Fourier transform and understanding examples like these would help me a lot.

Comment: The inverse looks something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+fourier+transform+of+1%2Fsqrt%28xi%29)

Comment: @Loophole Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a bit more theoretical answer, but it is good to know that it exists. For example, I would be happy to infer theoretically that the inverse Fourier transform is smooth when $t \neq 0$.

Comment: For clarification, do you really want $1/\sqrt{\xi}$ or instead $1/\sqrt{|\xi|}$?

Comment: Subject to the above clarification, this may be a duplicate of [($n$-dimensional) Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{\omega} \|^{2\alpha}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48430)