# Inverse fourier transform of $1/(\sqrt x+ia)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, contour-integration, complex-integration, branch-cuts

I am trying to analytically calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega \frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{\sqrt{\omega}+ia},$$
where $a>0$. The integrand has a branch cut with the branch point at $\omega=0$. Following an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318217/inverse-fourier-transform-of-frac1-sqrt-xi), and on using Mathematica, a similar integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega \frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{\sqrt{\omega}}$ (branch point at $\omega=0$) does have a closed form solution $(1-i)\Theta(-t)/\sqrt{|t|}$, but these don't provide a way to obtain this result anyway.

In principle, even just proving that the result should vanish for either $t>0$ or $t<0$, without obtaining the exact value, would be fine.

**Attempt at the second similar integral**: Making the substitution $\omega=\text{sgn}(\omega)\Omega^2$ following the comments,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega \frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{\sqrt{\omega}}=2\int_{0}^\infty d\Omega e^{-i\Omega^2 t}+ 2\int_\infty^0 (-d\Omega) \frac{e^{i\Omega^2 t}}{\pm i},$$
where the sign $+(-)$ corresponds to $\omega=-\Omega^2+(-)i\eta$, with $\eta\to 0^+$, on choosing the negative real axis as the branch cut. We choose $\omega=-\Omega^2+(-)i\eta$ for $t<(>)0$. Using the Fresnel integrals $\int_0^\infty dx\cos(x^2)=\int_0^\infty dx\sin(x^2)=\sqrt{\pi/8}$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega \frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{\sqrt{\omega}}=\sqrt{2\pi}(1-i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}\Theta(-t).$$

But the actual problem generates the integrals $\int_0^\infty d\Omega \frac{e^{-i\Omega^2 t}}{\Omega+ ia}$ and $\int_0^\infty d\Omega \frac{e^{i\Omega^2 t}}{\pm i\Omega+ ia}$, instead of the simpler Fresnel integrals, which seem intractable.

Comment: The integrand has a branch point at $\omega=0$,not at $\omega =-a^2$.

Comment: Silly mistake, corrected.

Comment: Have you made the transformation $\omega \mapsto \omega^2$?

Comment: Added my attempt

Comment: There is a simple reason why the integral vanishes for $t>0$: The integrand is analytic on the upper half-plane, vanishes fast enough if $t>0$ and $\Im\omega>0$, and the integral vanishes on the tiny semi-circle around $\omega=0$. Then apply the residue theorem to the obvious closed contour. [You can choose any branch cut for $\sqrt\omega$ that runs away from the closed contour and it works because $a>0$.]