# The Fourier transform of homogeneous function

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x)$ is homogeneous function of degree $a$, with $-n<a<0$, does the function always has Fourier transform? If not, what if $f$ is a continuous function

Answer (score 5):

If a function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and homogeneous of negative degree, then it's identically zero. So the Fourier transform exists, and is identically zero.

If you mean "continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$", that is a more interesting case. Actually, just being bounded on the unit sphere is enough for $f$ to be locally integrable with decay at infinity. Hence, it is a tempered distribution and therefore has a well-defined Fourier transform. As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48446), the transform is also homogeneous, with the degree of homogeneity $-n-a$.